# Change default file type from RTF to .DOC for Save As function with programmatically generated Word doc

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net page where users can download an MS Word document. On Server side, the logic reads the a .RTF, and changes its file extension to .DOC like below. The problem is that when the default file type is still .RTF, when users click SAVE As on the Word processor menu.

```
string sb = GetWordTemplate("/My.rtf");
//logic to replace place holder with text
Response.ContentType="application/msword"; 
Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition",
            string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.doc", name);
Byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sb);
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.End();
```

Any idea?

**Update**

No third party tool is used to modify RTF file, It simply replaces place holder with text.

The RTF file is actually .TXT file, but changed to have .RTF file extension.

The downloaded .DOC can be opened and saved successfully. But its default file type is still .RTF when Save As is used, which is the problem of this post.

This is a legacy code that I started to work on.

Comment: what library are you using to modify the rtf document?

Comment: RTF and DOC are completely different formats - the one is text, the other binary. You *can't* convert the one to the other simply by changing the extension. `DOC` is deprecated anyway. If you want to create a real Word document I suggest you use the Open XML SDK to create a `docx` file.

Comment: Please find my update above.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert between different document formats by just changing the file extension.

User's are still able to open the malformed file because Microsoft Word supports opening RTF files too.

The proper way to convert the file is by using Microsoft Office Interop Assemblies:

```
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var currentDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\yourdocument.rtf");
currentDoc.SaveAs(@"C:\yourdocument.doc", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument97);
```

This will save the document as doc in a specified location. You can read the contents of this file and return the bytes to web browser as follows:

```
Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\yourdocument.doc");
Response.ContentType="application/msword"; 
Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition",
            string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.doc", name);
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.End();
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid saving it before the download? Does using Microsoft Office Interop Assemblies require installing MS Word/Office, or just copying DLL assemblies?

Comment: As far as i know, in order to use interop assemblies, you have to install Microsoft Office.

Comment: Installing MS Office might not be the best option.

Comment: If an answer has helped you in any way, it is a good idea to upvote it.